# blueimp Gallery - lightbox - customize for images and HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, blueimp

We're using blueimp for our gallery and have successfully implemented the slider to show both images and html5 videos with multiple sources using the approach below

Here is the div layer:

```
<div id="blueimp-video-carousel-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls blueimp-gallery-carousel " data-start-slideshow="false">
 <div class="slides"></div>
 <h3 class="title"></h3>
 <a class="prev">‹</a> 
 <a class="next">›</a>
 <p class="description"></p>
</div>
```

Here is a snippet of the for loop that populates the slider:

```
if (_media_type == 'video') {
    item['title'] = "title";
    item['type'] = "video/*";
    item['poster'] = media_thumbnail;
    item['description'] = "description";
    item['sources'] = [{href: _media_url_hls, type: "application/x-mpegurl"}, {href: _media_url_web, type: "video/mp4"}];
} else {
    item['title'] = "title";
    item['type'] = "image/jpeg";
    item['poster'] = media_thumbnail;
    item['description'] = "description";
}
objArr.push(item); 

//// omitted for brevity

blueimp.Gallery(objArr, { container: '#blueimp-video-carousel-gallery', carousel: 'true', preloadRange: 2, transitionSpeed: 400});
```

Next we wanted to implement the lightbox so we tried the following:

```
<div id="links" class="links"></div>
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
```

javascript for loop:

```
var linksContainer = $('#links');
var linksContainerData='';

//omitted for brevity
//video
linksContainerData +='<a href="'+_media_url+'" title="..." data-gallery="" class="blueimp-gallery-thumb-anchor"><img src="'+_media_thumbnail+'" ></a>';

//image
linksContainerData +='<a href="'+_media_url+'" title="..." data-gallery="" class="blueimp-gallery-thumb-anchor"><img src="'+_media_thumbnail+'" ></a>';

//after loop
$(linksContainer).append(linksContainerData);
```

This works for images but fails to load the videos.  We'd like to be able to use the lightbox but in the slider be able to play HTML5 HLS and MP4 videos.

I believe the onOpen and onSlide event callbacks could be used, we can access the data from a jascript array, but I'm not sure how to customize.

Is it possible to specify a div layer instead of the 'a' tag so the slider uses a custom div layer?

Any guidance you an provide is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
J

Comment: I haven't found a solution for this so I'm likely to move away from blueimp gallery at least for lightbox.  blueimp is based on swipejs which I found here so that might be an option also.  [link] (http://codepen.io/mr_alien/pen/qdVwBN) I'm sure blueimp could be modified to handle this scenario but I'm under time constraints.  Hope folks found some value in the code posted.  Thanks, J

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the light box to work with an onClick that opens the carousel with a single entry and works with images and video; video has playback in hls with mp4 fallback.

I found the solution with the help of these links:
https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/   (see source)
https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.js (note: global click handler)

So I ended up with this function:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-gallery]', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).data('gallery');
    var widget = $(id);
    var selected_media_id;
    var media_id;
    var obj;
    selected_media_id = widget.selector;
    console.log("objArr.length-->"+objArr.length);
    for (i=0; i<objArr.length; i++) {
    obj = objArr[i];
    if (selected_media_id == obj['title']) {
        break;
    }
    }
    return blueimp.Gallery([obj], { container : '#blueimp-gallery', carousel : true});
});
```

So I essentially fetch my identifier which is set in the attribute

```
data-gallery="identifier"
```

and loop through the array built as noted prior and then initialize the #blueimp-gallery with a single object wrapped in an array [obj].  Missing the [] threw me for a bit.

So now the onclick in the light box opens the modal with a single entry with an x to close which will work well enough for now.  For videos it opens with a poster background and play icon and plays hls in Mac Safari and mp4 in chrome.

The video controls are not great (basic player controls) and there is room for improvement but this does the basics of what I wanted to achieve.

Hope this helps.

-J